# How to create an array of arrays in yaml?

Tags: yaml

I have a yaml file I want to look like this:

```
failoverconfig:
  projectname: fairchild
  unitconfig:
    - subunit:
      id: 8
       - socket:
          powerunit: power-1
          powerport: 10
       - socket:
          powerunit: power-2
          powerport: 2
    - subunit:
      id: 9
       - socket:
          powerunit: power-1
          powerport: 10
       - socket:
          powerunit: power-2
          powerport: 2
```

Basically there are multiple subunits that each have multiple sockets. Each socket has a powerunit and a powerport. I've checked my YAML syntax and it seems to be illegal. I don't fully understand why.

How do I fix it and get the data structure I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is something like this instead:

```
failoverconfig:
  projectname: fairchild
  unitconfig:
    subunits:
      - id: 8
        sockets:
          - powerunit: power-1
            powerport: 10
          - powerunit: power-2
            powerport: 2
      - id: 9
        sockets:
          - powerunit: power-1
            powerport: 10
          - powerunit: power-2
            powerport: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question I came here for and that is in the title:

```yaml
-
  - a
  - b
```